# Making a matrix

Tags: c#, string, parsing, matrix

This is what I'm trying to do:

Write a C# program that parses a string like A = like A = [5 4 1; 3 6 1; 2 3 9] that creates a matrix A of m >= 2 rows and n >=1 columns.

I know how to create a matrix by entering in single integers at one time, but I don't know how to read it like this A = [5 4 1; 3 6 1; 2 3 9] and create a matrix from it.
I am hitting a wall. I don't know how to use parse in this manner. I need some advice and suggestions.

I did something like this:

```
        string x;
        int m;
        int n;

        Console.WriteLine("Enter two no's seperated by space: ");

        x = Console.ReadLine();
        m = Convert.ToInt32(x.Split(' ')[0]);
        n = Convert.ToInt32(x.Split(' ')[1]);

        Console.WriteLine("" + m + " " + n);
```

but where would parse come into play?

edited:
Am I mistaking what parse is? is string.split parsing?

edited:
I try using the code they have on msdn: it uses foreach and that puts each element on a different line. How would I put it into a 3x3 matrix format?

```
    char[] delimiterChars = { ' ', ',', '.', ':', '\t' ,'[' ,']', ';', '"', 'A', '=' };

    string text = "A = [5 4 1; 3 6 1; 2 3 9]";
    System.Console.WriteLine("Original text: '{0}'", text);

    string[] words = text.Split(delimiterChars);
    System.Console.WriteLine("{0} words in text:", words.Length);

    foreach (string element in words)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(element);
    }

    // Keep the console window open in debug mode.
    System.Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
    System.Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: You can start by reading about  `string.Split` or  `Regex`

Comment: I did something like this:               string x;
            int m;
            int n;

            Console.WriteLine("Enter two no's seperated by space: ");

            x = Console.ReadLine();
            m = Convert.ToInt32(x.Split(' ')[0]);
            n = Convert.ToInt32(x.Split(' ')[1]);

            Console.WriteLine("" + m + " "  + n);

Comment: To clarify your terminology confusion, parsing is just the process of taking a string and converting it into a usable object. It doesn't refer to a particular method, or class (though of course there are many parsing methods and classes provided by the BCL).

Comment: thank you nick! I was so confuse. I thought parsing was a method or something of a keyword. I did not know that it was a process.

Answer (score 0):

A little Regex, string split along with Linq

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input = "A = [5 4 1; 3 6 1; 2 3 9]";

            string pattern = @"(?'name'\w+)\s+=\s+\[(?'numbers'[^\]]+)\]";
            Match match = Regex.Match(input, pattern);
            string name = match.Groups["name"].Value;

            string numbers = match.Groups["numbers"].Value;

            List<List<int>> array = numbers.Split(new char[] { ';' }).Select(x => x.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(z => int.Parse(z)).ToList()).ToList();
        }
    }
}
​
```

Comment: I looked at you code and it helped me more. thank you! but what would I Console.WriteLine()?

Comment: put WriteLine() into two for loops : for(int m = 0; m < array.count; m++) {for(int n = 0; n < 3; n++){}}